# What can I do if I use class "yathesis" and the chapter title is too long?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, yathesis

I use the class `yathesis` to edit my thesis. There is a problem: the titles of several chapters are very long, so in the page headers, a bad result is produced like this picture:

Picture:
[image]

The text of the title spills out from the page and the distance between the header text and page number is too small. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What to do? Please provide a MWE, that's the first step. A single screen shot does not reveal much, but I suspect that you have to shorten your chapter title ;-)

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean by MWE?

Comment: Have a look here: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: In most classes you can say something like `\chapter[<short title for header>]{<long title for start of chapter>}`. I don't know `yathesis` at all but probably it supports something of this kind....

Comment: You could also consider the chapter title itself. "Exerting" may not be required; it doesn't add anything not already implied by "Forces".  I assume "Collective" is important, but the "and...and" construction could possibly use some work, whether you mean "External (Contact Forces and Torques) and Some Othert Effect" or "External (Contact Forces and Torques and something".  In the first case it's not immediately clear what you mean, in the second the first and just needs replacing with a comma (so I'm guessing it's the first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can say something like:

```
\chapter[<short title for header>]{<long title for start of chapter>}
```

This uses `<long title for start of chapter>` to typeset the title of the chapter itself, but will use `<short title for header>` in the header.

Some non-standard classes may offer additional refinements, but most will at least support this one.